# How can I replace a string parameter with a custom parameter?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am new to gulp, This is the code:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

let tasks = [
    ['html'],
    ['src/*.html']
];


gulp.task('html', async () => {
    gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})


let currentSrc = tasks[1, 0]
let currentTask = tasks[0, 0]
gulp.task('watch', async () => {

    // no error but doesn't work:
    gulp.watch(currentSrc.toString(), gulp.series('html'));
    // this works instead:
    // gulp.watch('src/*.html', gulp.series('html'));

})
```

I wanted to make parameters more readable but I can't replace any them. The strings are identical, both are typeof String,
also `tasks[1][0] === 'src/*.html'`

Why aren't they interchangeable if they are identical?

When I use `gulp watch` in terminal, it doesn't give me an error, but it does not work also. I checked everything else and the problem is 100%  `tasks[1][0] !== 'src/*.html'` for some reason. I have only a few hair left :(

Solved: My final snippet

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

const tasks = [
    ['html'],
    ['src/*.html']
];

gulp.task('html', async () => {
    gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})

let currentSrc = tasks[1][0].toString();
let currentTask = gulp.series(tasks[0][0])
gulp.task('watch', async () => {

    gulp.watch(currentSrc, currentTask);

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `tasks[1, 0]` in your code. It needs to be `tasks[1][0]`.

```js
let tasks = [
    ['html', 'imagemin', 'minify'],
    ['src/*.html', 'src/images/*', 'src/javascript/*']
];

console.log(tasks[1, 0])
```

You didn't do a basic check to validate your assumption. Run that snippet, which is from your code in the question.

Then run this one:

```js
    const tasks = [
        ['html', 'imagemin', 'minify'],
        ['src/*.html', 'src/images/*', 'src/javascript/*']
    ];

    console.log(tasks[1][0])
```

You would have found this if you just reduced it to the Minimal Reproducible Example. 80% of the time you will find the problem when you do this.

Also, [use `const`](http://joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/shun-the-mutant/).

Re-reading your question, it looks like it just might have been a typo in your code that you didn't see. If you stare at it for half a day, that'll happen!

Comment: I tested with currentSrc.toString(), it doesn't seem to work. I am probably missing something but i can't find it.  I added what I tried lastly

Comment: You have `tasks[1, 0]` in your code. It needs to be `tasks[1][0]`

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. I was staring at it for a long time like you said, thank you very much. Thanks for reminding me to use const too. I will cut the unnecessary parts in the snippet so if anyone reads this threads later they don't have to read unrelevant code

Comment: You're welcome. Happens to all of us! Sometimes you just need fresh eyes. Feel free to accept it as the solution.